# how to always show homescreen after unlocking?

Tags: root-access, lock-screens, home-screen, gestures

On a Nexus 5 and I am looking for a way to configure it to always show the homescreen after unlocking it. is it possible? how?

Right now, after unlocking it shows the screen exactly as it was left it before being locked. I have not yet managed to get the habit of pressing the home button (i.e. go to homescreen) before I press the power button (i.e. lock my screen)...

p.s. this device is rooted.

Comment: Can you Include your Android version?

Comment: on that Nexus I have Android 6.0.1    On another device I have 7.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the only way to get this without automation is having the habit of pressing "show desktop" before locking.

In case, you are not against automation, you can accomplish your request with MacroDroid, Tasker or other apps.

With MacroDroid

1. In the Triggers section, select Screen Unlocked.
2. In the Actions section, select Launch Home Screen.
3. Give the macro a name, then save it.

When you unlock the screen, the home screen will be shown (there was about 300 ms delay when testing) even if another app was in the foreground.

Comment: hhmm... yes, that it a way to get it. But I don't wish to have automation. I'd prefer to edit code somewhere with my fingertips (: